# Global and response as Json?

Tags: playframework-2.2

I'm adding my specific response to 404/500 errors returned by my Play!Framework application, and in some case, I'd like it to return a Json like answer (as text, it doesn't matter).

I tried this :

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.libs.F.Promise;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader;
import play.mvc.SimpleResult;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable t) {
        if (play.Play.isDev()) {
            return super.onError(request, t);
        }

        if ("/api/".equals(request.path().substring(0, 5))) {
            ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
            result.put("error", "Internal server error.");
            result.put("code", "500");

            return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(internalServerError(result));
        }
        else {
            return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(internalServerError(
                views.html.internalServerError.render()
            ));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
        if (play.Play.isDev()) {
            return super.onHandlerNotFound(request);
        }

        if ("/api/".equals(request.path().substring(0, 5))) {
            ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
            result.put("error", "Url not found.");
            result.put("code", "404");

            return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(internalServerError(result));
        }
        else {
            return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(notFound(
                views.html.notFound.render()
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

But I got a `error: cannot find symbol` located at the line with `internalServerError`.

I believe `internalServerError` expect a rendered template, but how can I instead specify a Json object (or at least a string) ?

Comment: Could you include your imports? `internalServerError(String content)` and `internalServerError(JsonNode content)` included in `play.mvc.Results`

Comment: I added the import in the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing `Results` and calling `Results.internalServerError(result)` and so on should get rid of the compilation error.

```
import play.mvc.Results;

...
return F.Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(Results.internalServerError(result));
```

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea why (and how) when I return a notFound() in one of my controller, it's not caught in the `onHandlerNotFound` method ?

Comment: I believe `onHandlerNotFound` is called when no action was found to serve a request. So if some user calls http://yourApp/api/this_path_does_not_exist `onHandlerNotFound` is called. However, if you return `notFound()` after a request was routed to some action, it doesn't qualify as a 'handler not found'. You could inject `Global` to your controller and call `onHandlerNotFound(request)` directly instead of `notFound()`. You would have to investigate if that's a good idea or not.